# javafx.scene.control.ComboBox closes its listbox when touch and scroll list

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

Follow this steps on IOS or ANDROID:

1 - touch on combobox to open its listbox with many itens on list
2 - when try scroll list, its listbox closes

[before open de combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZno5.jpg)

[when ty to scroll list the listbox closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPaQY.jpg)

I would like the possibility to scroll list until to find the correct item, and only after I touch on the item, the list box closes.

What can I do to have this behavior?

Comment: JavaFx on Android? By Gluon? You won't get happy with that in future. Same thing as Ionic. As an Android developer I would never recommend this. I experienced the wildest stuff with "different versions" in Android devices at nearly EVERY SDK version and I guarantee, that this problems can not be solved using a "wrapper framework". If you want "one code base" then write a web-app, which runs in a native webview container. Or write a shared REST backend and separate UIs for each OS, which are executing the REST services.

Comment: If you are just at the beginning of the app, get lost on Gluon, otherwise "good luck". PS: Nothing against Gluon or Ionic,the idea itself is great, but nearly impossible to master.

Comment: Helo @DavidWeber. Thanks to answer this question and share your experience. PS: I've already gave up from Gluon.

Comment: My pleasure. :)